# Does SaveChangesAsync() wait for triggers to be executed

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, triggers, entity-framework-core

If for example there is a trigger defined on row insert of a table,
will `await context.SaveChangesAsync();` wait for all triggers to be completely executed as well before returning the number of state entries?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, triggers are part of the operation so a statement will only return when triggers have completed. That's SQL Server, nothing to do with EF.

Comment: Ok. I just haven't found any official statement at Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like any results generated by a trigger get included in the response back to your application.  I'm reading this to mean that (as the comments indicate) this is part of the operation: query runs, trigger fires, back to your application.  So yes triggers are executed before resuming from the await.

> When a trigger fires, results are returned to the calling application, just like with stored procedures. To prevent having results returned to an application because of a trigger firing, do not include either SELECT statements that return results or statements that perform variable assignment in a trigger. A trigger that includes either SELECT statements that return results to the user or statements that perform variable assignment requires special handling; these returned results would have to be written into every application in which modifications to the trigger table are allowed. If variable assignment must occur in a trigger, use a SET NOCOUNT statement at the start of the trigger to prevent the return of any result sets.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql